# How does the main character of Midnight Mass, a vampire, gain the ability to operate in the daytime?

Tags: vampire, f-paul-wilson, midnight-mass

This is not my question, actually, but the fellow [here](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/posts.php?discussion=14247629080A29117400&page=1) didn't follow up when I suggested he go to this Stack Exchange and now I'm a bit curious. I have his question stated verbatim below:

> So I no longer own a copy of *Midnight Mass* by F. Paul Wilson (author of the [*Repairman Jack*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/RepairmanJack) novels, which I haven't read) and I really don't want to go out and buy a copy just to trope something I vaguely remember, but I was hoping maybe someone here owns it or has read it and has a better memory than I.
>
> I doubt anyone would sustain an actual discussion about the book, as obscure as it is, so here's my question:
>
> The main character gets turned into a vampire. Then **something** happens to him that makes him able to stay conscious later into the morning, and wake up earlier in the evening, than other vampires, giving him an advantage over them. He has all of their abilities and strengths, but he can be awake longer than them, allowing him to kill them while they're vulnerable.
>
> The problem is I can't remember what it was that gave him this ability. I know it involved him being in the sun, but it was not just that.
>
> I would really appreciate it if anyone knows.

I have a copy of the book requested from my library, but I also don't have a huge amount of time to read additional books at the moment, so I don't know if I'll be able to get him an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just scanned through the book, and all I can find is this:

> Of course. Franco had expected him to rise from the dead in the
>   rectory and start feeding on the parishioners. He must know by now
>   that that hadn't happened. He'd want to know why. Never in a thousand
>   years would he guess the truth.

And this:

> "Yes!" Joe heard the word hiss out like escaping steam. "The priest.
>   Killing me wasn't good enough. You had to condemn me to an eternity of
>   depravity, rob me of every shred of dignity, undo every scrap of good
>   I'd done in my entire life. At least that was your plan. But it didn't
>   work."
>  "How?" The word was an exhalation.
>  "I'm not even sure
>   myself. All I know is this is how it works out in the end: I lose, but
>   you lose too."

I don't think it's ever explicitly explained. I suspect it was a one-in-a-million combination of: a) He was turned by a weak feral vamp; b) He was a priest with very strong beliefs; c) He was surrounded by people that still loved him.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a few years since I read Mr. Wilson's "Midnight Mass". As I recall, two female characters (A niece, I believe, and a nun friend) unearthed or discovered the protagonist's body on the morning after he was vampire-bitten, before he'd had the time to complete his transformation. His body was exposed to sunlight until it began to smoke, then the ladies moved him into the shade. This exposure to sunlight before he was completely vampirized seemed to have saved him from the full transformation: He could withstand a short exposure to sunlight; he had difficulty entering a building without an invitation, but could force himself across the threshold; He felt no blood-hunger, but could not take food and required a drop of blood every day to survive. Also, he wished that death would end his condition, whereas full vampires feared death.
The ladies may also have performed christian services over his body.