# Does the miniseries "Midnight Mass" have any relation with the book of the same name?

Tags: midnight-mass, midnight-mass-2021

The miniseries *Midnight Mass* shares its name with a book that has similar themes, published by a reasonably well-known author in 1990. In fact, the book already has a question [on this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82738/how-does-the-main-character-of-midnight-mass-a-vampire-gain-the-ability-to-ope).

The description of the book on Google Books notes the following:

> Falsely accused of abuse, Father Dan is drunk in a basement waiting
> for the end. His superior has betrayed the local Catholic congregation
> and become a vampire.

On the one hand, the two have vampires, priests, and alcohol problems in common. On the other hand...everything else?

> Sister Carolyn has become a formidable killer of cowboys and vampires. Dan's niece, escaped from the conquest of New
> York, has made her way south to find him. Brought together by Rabbi
> Zev Wolpin, who is shaken by the vampires' fear of the cross and holy
> water, they plan their resistance. Against all odds, they discover
> that there just might be a way for humanity to really fight back. But
> first they will have to kill the vampire king of New York.

Is there any connection, if only in terms of the loose outline of the story or having bought the intellectual property rights, between the 2021 miniseries and the 1990 book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Bustle, there's no relation between the two.

> To be clear, there is a book called Midnight Mass. Written by F. Paul
> Wilson, the 1990 action novel is full of vampires, cowboys, and
> vigilante nuns. **But while it may share some surface similarities with
> Flanagan’s show, it has no relation to it at all.** As Flanagan
> [explained to Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/tv/midnight-mass-mike-flanagan-journey/), the idea for Midnight Mass had been
> "bopping around" in his head for as long as he could recall. He wrote
> several different drafts of the story over the years, starting as far
> back as 2013. "It was a movie, it was a novel, it was a series,” he
> said. When he realized it was too long to be a film, Flanagan started
> shopping it around as a TV show, but “everyone passed.” Still, he
> “always thought of [it] as the best project I would never make.”

Confirmed by the author of the book in a twit after whats-on-netflix [erroneously identified the new show as being based on his book](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EdJ44YhWoAAk_0i?format=png&name=large).

> **F. Paul Wilson:** It's not my MIDNIGHT MASS. People have been asking me about this but it's an error. (I wish it weren't - I think @flanaganfilm  would do a good job.)
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/fpaulwilson/status/1284221824159670273)</sup></sub>